# "Default decoder could not decode result"

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, httpservice, actionresult

Here are the files -

MXML:

```
<mx:HTTPService id="score" url="http://...score.php" fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)"
method="POST" result=""mx.controls.Alert.show(event.result.toString())">
            <s:request xmlns="">
                <name>{name}</name>
                <score>{score}</score>
            </s:request>
        </mx:HTTPService>
```

score.php

```
<?php

    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";

    $connections = mysql_connect("...");
    mysql_select_db("...");

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO hs (name, score) VALUES ('$name', '$score')"; 
    mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Information does sends successfully creating and doing the query above. But "result" event gives "Default decoder could not decode result" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what will say this code for you?

```
<mx:HTTPService id="scoreService" url="http://" method="POST" fault="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.fault.faultString)" result="mx.controls.Alert.show(event.result.toString())">
    <s:request xmlns="">
        <name>myName</name>
        <score>myScore</score>
    </s:request>
</mx:HTTPService>
```

did you see [this](http://anybodyshero.blogspot.com/2008/03/flex-3-and-php.html) and [this](http://www.flexdeveloper.eu/forums/mxml/database-connectivity-problems/), do you have some difference in client/server side?

Comment: there I have variables - <name>{name}</name>
    <score>{score}</score>

Comment: The fact is that it does post data to my database. So it does perform what I need by inserting a row in the database...

Comment: is your url really works? are you on Apache or Tomcat or IIS? Do you have a logs to see them?

Comment: can you show the output of your service via browser with that params u r using in flex. please. does it have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` string at a top.

Comment: ok, I see it does not, return URL is completely different and I know what the problem is now, thnx!